# A Complete Sigil Guide for SOUL SACRIFICE DELTA

Tags: soul-sacrifice, soul-sacrifice-delta

Is there a complete walkthrough for unlocking all Sigils in Soul Sacrifice 
Delta?

I have seen the wiki [here](http://soulsacrifice.wikia.com/wiki/Delta:Sigils), but it's still quite incomplete. The wiki is unclear on how to unlock some of the sigils, specifically most on the Palm and the Godblood sigils.

I have searched online documents but to no avail, and I'm starting to think that I can only get my answers if I try to translate Japanese sites where SSD was much more popular (and I don't know which japanese sites these are even).

If there isn't, I was hoping I can at least get information on how to unlock Sentinel V,GodBlood VI and GodBloodVII, Resolute and Taboo Tree Sigils

Comment: as I cannot create new tags yet, can someone include the tag "Soul Sacrifice Delta"? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a spreadsheet with more sigils [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18wn4vbD7EFEfAz-9NJUc0zXp9drGUXGevGey2aCRuWc/edit#gid=1023520523), and I have been able to confirm that Sentinel V (Line 417), GodBlood VI and VII (Lines 384 and 385), Resolute (Line 450), and Taboo Tree (Line 448) are all on there.

Comment: Generally, it's a good idea to summarize the linked content here.  At least for the specific Sigils mentioned.  That way, this answer is still good if that doc ever gets removed.